# How to grab a certain item from this python requests repsonse

Tags: python, python-requests

I have this response in json form but I am having a lot of trouble understanding how to grab the certain item that I need, if anyone could explain to me how that would be great thanks. I am trying to get into 'kills', then 'value'. I have tried using:

```
kills = data['data']['kills']['value']
print(kills)
```

But that won't work.

```
{
   "data":{
      "platformInfo":{
         "platformSlug":"origin",
         "platformUserId":"not_aqex",
         "platformUserHandle":"not_aqex",
         "platformUserIdentifier":"not_aqex",
         "avatarUrl":"https://secure.download.dm.origin.com/production/avatar/prod/1/599/208x208.JPEG",
         "additionalParameters":null
      },
      "userInfo":{
         "userId":null,
         "isPremium":false,
         "isVerified":false,
         "isInfluencer":false,
         "countryCode":null,
         "customAvatarUrl":null,
         "customHeroUrl":null,
         "socialAccounts":[
            
         ]
      },
      "metadata":{
         "currentSeason":2,
         "activeLegend":"legend_9",
         "activeLegendName":"Octane"
      },
      "segments":[
         {
            "type":"overview",
            "attributes":{
               
            },
            "metadata":{
               "name":"Lifetime"
            },
            "expiryDate":"2020-09-30T03:10:32.6124204+00:00",
            "stats":{
               "level":{
                  "rank":null,
                  "percentile":null,
                  "displayName":"Level",
                  "displayCategory":"Combat",
                  "category":null,
                  "metadata":{
                     
                  },
                  "value":65,
                  "displayValue":"65",
                  "displayType":"Unspecified"
               },
               "kills":{
                  "rank":null,
                  "percentile":null,
                  "displayName":"Kills",
                  "displayCategory":"Combat",
                  "category":null,
                  "metadata":{
                     
                  },
                  "value":427,
                  "displayValue":"427",
                  "displayType":"Unspecified"
               },
               "seasonWins":{
                  "rank":null,
                  "percentile":null,
                  "displayName":"Season 1 Wins",
                  "displayCategory":"Game",
                  "category":null,
                  "metadata":{
                     
                  },
                  "value":0,
                  "displayValue":"0",
                  "displayType":"Unspecified"
               },
               "rankScore":{
                  "rank":null,
                  "percentile":null,
                  "displayName":"Rank Score",
                  "displayCategory":"Game",
                  "category":null,
                  "metadata":{
                     "iconUrl":"https://trackercdn.com/cdn/apex.tracker.gg/ranks/gold3.png",
                     "rankName":"Gold 3"
                  },
                  "value":3650,
                  "displayValue":"3,650",
                  "displayType":"Unspecified"
               },
               "season4Wins":{
                  "rank":null,
                  "percentile":null,
                  "displayName":"Season 4 Wins",
                  "displayCategory":"Game",
                  "category":null,
                  "metadata":{
                     
                  },
                  "value":10,
                  "displayValue":"10",
                  "displayType":"Unspecified"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "type":"legend",
            "attributes":{
               "id":"legend_9"
            },
            "metadata":{
               "name":"Octane",
               "imageUrl":"https://trackercdn.com/cdn/apex.tracker.gg/legends/octane-tile.png",
               "tallImageUrl":"https://trackercdn.com/cdn/apex.tracker.gg/legends/octane-tall.png",
               "bgImageUrl":"https://trackercdn.com/cdn/apex.tracker.gg/legends/octane-concept-bg-small.jpg",
               "isActive":true
            },
            "expiryDate":"2020-09-30T03:10:32.6124204+00:00",
            "stats":{
               "kills":{
                  "rank":null,
                  "percentile":79,
                  "displayName":"Kills",
                  "displayCategory":"Combat",
                  "category":null,
                  "metadata":{
                     
                  },
                  "value":279,
                  "displayValue":"279",
                  "displayType":"Unspecified"
               },
               "season4Wins":{
                  "rank":null,
                  "percentile":96.7,
                  "displayName":"Season 4 Wins",
                  "displayCategory":"Game",
                  "category":null,
                  "metadata":{
                     
                  },
                  "value":10,
                  "displayValue":"10",
                  "displayType":"Unspecified"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "type":"legend",
            "attributes":{
               "id":"legend_7"
            },
            "metadata":{
               "name":"Lifeline",
               "imageUrl":"https://trackercdn.com/cdn/apex.tracker.gg/legends/lifeline-tile.png",
               "tallImageUrl":"https://trackercdn.com/cdn/apex.tracker.gg/legends/lifeline-tall.png",
               "bgImageUrl":"https://trackercdn.com/cdn/apex.tracker.gg/legends/lifeline-concept-bg-small.jpg",
               "isActive":false
            },
            "expiryDate":"2020-09-30T03:10:32.6124204+00:00",
            "stats":{
               "kills":{
                  "rank":null,
                  "percentile":69,
                  "displayName":"Kills",
                  "displayCategory":"Combat",
                  "category":null,
                  "metadata":{
                     
                  },
                  "value":136,
                  "displayValue":"136",
                  "displayType":"Unspecified"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "type":"legend",
            "attributes":{
               "id":"legend_8"
            },
            "metadata":{
               "name":"Pathfinder",
               "imageUrl":"https://trackercdn.com/cdn/apex.tracker.gg/legends/pathfinder-tile.png",
               "tallImageUrl":"https://trackercdn.com/cdn/apex.tracker.gg/legends/pathfinder-tall.png",
               "bgImageUrl":"https://trackercdn.com/cdn/apex.tracker.gg/legends/pathfinder-concept-bg-small.jpg",
               "isActive":false
            },
            "expiryDate":"2020-09-30T03:10:32.6124204+00:00",
            "stats":{
               "seasonWins":{
                  "rank":null,
                  "percentile":null,
                  "displayName":"Season 1 Wins",
                  "displayCategory":"Game",
                  "category":null,
                  "metadata":{
                     
                  },
                  "value":0,
                  "displayValue":"0",
                  "displayType":"Unspecified"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "type":"legend",
            "attributes":{
               "id":"legend_5"
            },
            "metadata":{
               "name":"Bloodhound",
               "imageUrl":"https://trackercdn.com/cdn/apex.tracker.gg/legends/bloodhound-tile.png",
               "tallImageUrl":"https://trackercdn.com/cdn/apex.tracker.gg/legends/bloodhound-tall.png",
               "bgImageUrl":"https://trackercdn.com/cdn/apex.tracker.gg/legends/bloodhound-concept-bg-small.jpg",
               "isActive":false
            },
            "expiryDate":"2020-09-30T03:10:32.6124204+00:00",
            "stats":{
               "kills":{
                  "rank":null,
                  "percentile":43,
                  "displayName":"Kills",
                  "displayCategory":"Combat",
                  "category":null,
                  "metadata":{
                     
                  },
                  "value":12,
                  "displayValue":"12",
                  "displayType":"Unspecified"
               }
            }
         }
      ],
      "availableSegments":[
         {
            "type":"legend",
            "attributes":{
               
            },
            "metadata":{
               
            }
         }
      ],
      "expiryDate":"2020-09-30T03:10:32.6124204+00:00"
   }
}
```

NOTE FROM EDITOR: I used [This cool online JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to clean up the supplied JSON data.  I use this tool frequently, and highly recommend it.

Comment: What error message do you have there?

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I also tried this instead, kills = data['data']['segments']['stats']['kills']['value']

Comment: ```data['data']['segments']``` there will return a list. So make sure that you grab the ```data['data']['segments'][0]['stats']['kills']'``` if you only want to grab the first kills.. You can do a for loop there to get all the kills from each segment

Comment: At what point do you notice that it will start returning a list instead of a ditionary?

Comment: Look at the square brackets indicating a list there. So the segments return a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trimmed version of your data with just the `kills` keys with each of their `value` keys:

```
{
   "data":{
      "segments":[
         {
            "stats":{
               "kills":{
                  "value":427,
               },
            }
         },
         {
            "stats":{
               "kills":{
                  "value":279,
               },
            }
         },
         {
            "stats":{
               "kills":{
                  "value":136,
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "stats":{
            }
         },
         {
            "stats":{
               "kills":{
                  "value":12,
               }
            }
         }
      ],
   }
}
```

Note that there are five "segment" dictionaries in a list under the `segments` key, but only four of these contain `kills` keys.  You can address the `value` item for each of these four with:

```
record['data']['segments'][0]['stats']['kills']['value']
record['data']['segments'][1]['stats']['kills']['value']
record['data']['segments'][2]['stats']['kills']['value']
record['data']['segments'][4]['stats']['kills']['value']
```

The `index == 3` entry in `segments` has no `kills` key, so while there are five segments, there are only four `kills/value` values.  Here's code to back that all up, along with the result of running this code:

```
data = """{
    "data":{
        "segments":[
           ...
}"""
       

record = json.loads(data)
print(record['data']['segments'][0]['stats']['kills']['value'])
print(record['data']['segments'][1]['stats']['kills']['value'])
print(record['data']['segments'][2]['stats']['kills']['value'])
try:
    print(record['data']['segments'][3]['stats']['kills']['value'])
except Exception:
    print("invalid reference")
print(record['data']['segments'][4]['stats']['kills']['value'])
```

Result:

```
427
279
136
invalid reference
12
```

Note that although I show the trimmed version of the data above, I ran this code on the complete version of the data as provided, which is indeed valid JSON.

Comment: so when the [ comes up that indicates a list, then each dictionary is at an index inside that list correct, and thanks for the help I am still trying to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Just an extention to @steve's answer

More trimmed version for better visualization

```
   "data":
   {          
      "segments":
      [
            {"stats":{"kills":{"value":427}}},
            {"stats":{"kills":{"value":279}}},
            {"stats":{"kills":{"value":136}}},
            {"stats":{"seasonWins":{"value":0}}},
            {"stats":{"kills":{"value":12}}},
      ],
      "availableSegments":
      [
         {"type":"legend", "attributes":{}, "metadata":{}}
      ],
      "expiryDate":"2020-09-30T03:10:32.6124204+00:00"
   }
```

For loop to understand better

```
for segments in data['data']['segments']:
    if 'kills' in segments['stats']:      # condition when expected node is not present
        print(segments['stats']['kills'])
        print(segments['stats']['kills']['value'])
```

Output

```
{'value': 427}
427
{'value': 279}
279
{'value': 136}
136
{'value': 12}
12
```

Comment: Nice addition!  I would have used `segment` instead of `stats`, but that's a minor gripe for sure.

Comment: This is pretty sick as well, this is all new to me so showing new ways to sort through all this data is a lot of help, thanks.